# Limiting Network Requests on Observable via an RxJS Operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have some data coming into a component in my Angular app via a network request. This is an `observable` and looks like this:

```
    this.streamFiltersService.getByFilters(
        this.page - 1, this.pagesize, this.currentStage, this.language = filters['language'], this.location = filters['location'],
        this.zipcode = filters['zip'], this.firstName = filters['firstName'], this.lastName = filters['lastName'],
        this.branch = filters['branch'], fn);
```

There is a callback here called `fn`, which looks like this:

```
    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
    };
```

The problem I'm running into is that, as numerous firings of the filter come into the component, I end up with multiple network requests - and for the user, the screen data changes several times. Furthermore, because this is asynchronous, sometimes one of the first requests comes back last, and the filters are not applied in the screen the user sees.

The full function looks like this:

```
public onFilterReceived(values)
{
    let filters = {};

    if (values) {
        filters = values;
    }

    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params: any) => {
            this.page = params['page'];
        }
    );

    console.log('onFilterReceived() firing...');

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
    };

    this.streamFiltersService.getByFilters(
        this.page - 1, this.pagesize, this.currentStage, this.language = filters['language'], this.location = filters['location'],
        this.zipcode = filters['zip'], this.firstName = filters['firstName'], this.lastName = filters['lastName'],
        this.branch = filters['branch'], fn);
}
```

As a follow-up, when I put a `console.log` on the callback within `onFilterReceived()`, like so:

```
let fn = async resRecordsData => {
    console.log('records: ', resRecordsData);
    this.records = await resRecordsData;
};
```

What prints to the console is this:

```
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(1), count: 1}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(12), count: 115}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(1), count: 1}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(1), count: 1}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(1), count: 1}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(12), count: 115}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(12), count: 115}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(12), count: 115}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(12), count: 115}
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(12), count: 115}
```

Please make note that, because I have a filter applied, the correct value is the Array(1). As you can see, because these calls are asynchronous, they come back out of order. What I ideally want is one call, that results in this:

```
records:  {ok: true, status: 200, statusText: "OK", data: Array(1), count: 1}
```

Based on a suggestion below, I tried chaining the suggested operators within the callback of `onFilterReceived()`, like so:

```
public async onFilterReceived(values)
{
    let filters = {};

    if (values) {
        filters = values;
    }

    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params: any) => {
            this.page = params['page'];
        }
    );

    console.log('onFilterReceived() firing...');

    let fn = async resRecordsData => {
        await resRecordsData
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .debounceTime(1000)
        .switchMap( resRecordsData => {
            this.records = resRecordsData;
        });
        console.log('records: ', this.records);
    };

    this.streamFiltersService.getByFilters(
        this.page - 1, this.pagesize, this.currentStage, this.language = filters['language'], this.location = filters['location'],
        this.zipcode = filters['zip'], this.firstName = filters['firstName'], this.lastName = filters['lastName'],
        this.branch = filters['branch'], fn);
}
```

... but I end up with an error:

> error_handler.js:60 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   resRecordsData.distinctUntilChanged is not a function

Comment: You could use [debounceTime](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/debouncetime.html) in rxjs. Eg. [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-material-data-table/)

Answer (score 2):

So if i understand your issues correctly:

- you maintain global state (`this.records`) via async callbacks
- http requests are fired but come back unordered.

This is very much alike the often repeated [autocomplete example with rxjs](https://medium.com/@rachel.poulos/wreck-the-web-with-observables-how-to-make-an-autocomplete-search-with-rxjs-bd588ad91b1b).

The code you will need will be something along these lines:

```
$filterChanges
  .distinctUntilchanged()
  .debounceTime(1000)
  .switchMap(filters => getByFilters(.....))
  .subscribe(records => {
    // modify global state with the records
  });
```

So you first take a stream of your filters and their changes - for instance `{ page, pagesize, currentStage, language }`. You might have to add a `compareFunc` to the `distinctUntilChanged` for the filters object because it is a non-primitive.

Below is a crude example non-angular implementation to help you out:

```js
/* make our html filter elements observable */
var carTypeFilter = document.getElementById('cars');
var hornsCheckbox = document.getElementById('horns');

var $carsFilter = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(carTypeFilter, 'change')
  .map(evt => ({ filter: 'car', value: evt.target.value }));
var $hornsFilter = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(hornsCheckbox, 'change')
  .map(evt => ({ filter: 'horns', value: evt.target.checked }));

/* we want to have one value containing the current logical grouping of filters */
var $filtersCombined = Rx.Observable.merge($carsFilter,$hornsFilter)
  .scan((allCurrentFilters, currFilterItem) => {
    allCurrentFilters[currFilterItem.filter] = currFilterItem.value;
    return allCurrentFilters;
  }, {});


var $debouncedFilterChanges = $filtersCombined
  /* for distinctUntilChanged to work
  you would need to have a compareFunction to evaluate
  if all the key:value pairs of the filters are the same
  not going to do that in this example; it will only filter out 
  filter sets after franctic clicking but only result in an additional
  request being done to the backend */
  //  .distinctUntilChanged()
  /* for every distinct filterSetChange debounce it so 
  we know that the user has stopped fiddling with the inputs */
  .debounceTime(500);

var $filteredServerResults = $debouncedFilterChanges
  .switchMap(filters => getFilteredData(filters.car, filters.horns));

$filteredServerResults.subscribe(data => {
  document.getElementById('results').innerText = JSON.stringify(data);
});


/*
mock function which simulates doing async call to server with slow respons
*/
function getFilteredData(car, horns){
  //note that the car or horns can be undefined
  return Rx.Observable.of(`retrieved values for: ${car}-${horns}`)
    .delay(1500); // mimic slow response, user can have already asked newer results
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.12/Rx.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <select id="cars">
      <option value="">Select one...</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <label for="cars">Car</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="horns" name="feature"
           value="horns" />
    <label for="horns">HasHorns</label>
  </div>
  <h1>results...</h1>
  <pre id="results"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This looks right. My only question is where in my code does this chaining of operators take place? I added my full receiving function above -- "onFilterReceived()". It'd be much appreciated if you could let me know where I would chain on these operators in my code.

Comment: I tried using the chained operators you suggested within my callback above (code updated), but end up with an error (shown above).

Comment: I'm not clear what $filterChanges is as it pertains to my code.

Comment: i have added an example, hope this helps